# Какие API speech_recognition кроме recognize_google имеют поддержку русского языка?

Tags: python, api, распознавание-речи

Из всех возможных API:

- **recognize_bing()**
- **recognize_google()**
- **recognize_google_cloud()**
- **recognize_houndify()**
- **recognize_ibm()**
- **recognize_sphinx()**
- **recognize_wit()**

Я нашел русский только в recognize_google, искал в документации и инете, но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

[Vosk](https://pypi.org/project/vosk/) - понимает русский, к тому же умеет работать offline